# Should I provide a background for a question about metaphysics and software development?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions

I have a question about the relationship between metaphysics and a software development activity called "domain modeling".

The metaphysics part of the question is very basic and must be quite simple for anyone in this site to understand. But the domain modeling part, although relatively simple as well for a software developer, may be a bit tricky for a philosopher (or anyone with no programming background).

So, I'm thinking about writing a kind of "introduction" to domain modeling in my question to overcome this problem. But this would probably make the question long and perhaps a bit unfocused.

So, what should I do? Provide that background in the question or just assume that the reader will know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Perhaps you should come at this in steps. Write the question without the background, and see how people receive it. If it turns out that a lack of background hinders response, but that there is some general interest, then you can always go and edit more into your question.

Comment: Can you give us a bit more information about the actual question you're asking? If it is more related to software development than to metaphysics, you might consider asking on [Programmers.SE] instead.

Comment: @Cody The gist of it is: domain modeling involves some "metaphysical decisions" about how to represent the problem domain in software. In particular, one has to decide if a certain "being" in the reality should be represented as an *entity* or a *value* (basically the distinction between essence and accident in Aristotelian jargon); and also, how to represent the passage of time for an entity: as a series of changes of state or as a series of immutable states chained together by time; so what should I study in Metaphysics in order to gain a more insightful perspective on domain modeling?

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, dear mods. [Here](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/how-can-domain-modeling-practice-benefit-from-metaphysical-ideas) is my first stab at it.

Comment: @OtavioMacedo: I, for one, found the question to be well-framed, and with an appropriate amount of background context (not too much, not too little.)

Comment: I don't know what you want to answer, but i'm VERY curious about it.

Answer (score 3):

As always, questions should be as self-contained as possible. Any terms or ideas which are not common knowledge should be explained. If the question is actually on-topic for this site (meaning it's primarily a philosophy question and not a programming question) then there's no need to worry about comprehension (provided you provide enough explanation for non-philosophy terms). That, and a good many of us are software developers too.